# jQuery Animation: Make a sprite appear to be walking, not floating/gliding

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I am writing a small jQuery animation script that simulates a delivery man walking up to a door. The animation works and all, but it just looks so artificial. I'm wondering if there is a way to make the sprite sort of bob back-and-forth to give the impression he is actually walking. I would hate to think the only way to do this would be to plot all the points - I'm hoping there is some sort of plugin out there that might be able to simplify this.

***[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Jaybles/ZYMsy/)*** (You'll need a wide monitor, the scene is 1102 px Wide)

Does anyone know of one?

**HTML**

```
<div class="indexHeader">
    <img src="http://img705.imageshack.us/img705/2410/deliveryman.png" class='deliveryMan' />
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.indexHeader{
    width:1102px;
    height:367px;
    background:url(http://img839.imageshack.us/img839/3298/indexheader2.png);
    overflow:hidden;  
}

.deliveryMan{
    position:relative;
    width:415px;
    height:520px;
    top:0px;
    left:450px;    
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.deliveryMan').animate({
    'left': '+=310px',
    'top': '+=30px',
    'width': '275px',
    'height': '344px'    
}, 4000);
```

Comment: Imageshack has blocked access to the sprite to prevent hotlinking, so I can't see your example.

Comment: Here is a version using Dummy Images (http://jsfiddle.net/Jaybles/ZYMsy/3/) ... Although the effect is sort of hard to see.

Comment: As Duopixel mentions below, you can try the easing plugin and have the position update using a sine curve pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My effect is still not quite there, but it's getting close.

1. Add the jQuery easing plug-in
2. Put the easeInOutBounce easing into your animation, but only to the "top" property

here is the jquery

```
$('.deliveryMan').animate({
    'left': '+=310px',
    'top': '+=30px',
    'width': '275px',
    'height': '344px'    
}, {
    duration: 4000,
    specialEasing: {
      top: 'easeInOutBounce'
    }
});
```

Try playing with the parameters.

http://jsfiddle.net/Hm7ZQ/

Comment: This is actually quite good! I would like to leave the question open for a few hours, but this is the front-runner right now. I will also stay tuned in case you add any updates. Thanks! +1 ... I wonder if there is anyway to animate a slight rotation as well.

Comment: I decided that this was probably the best solution of the ones presented here. Even though the suggestion by `sod` above has a more realistic effect, the `easing` method assures that the up/down motion is sync'd with the other animations' start/end times.

Answer (score 1):

Tried a bit with you fiddle example. Maybe you have to improve my numbers a bit more :-)

http://jsfiddle.net/eKCw6/2/

Comment: This is also quite nice. Thanks! +1

Answer (score 0):

You could use this great plugin, pretty much plug-and-play
http://www.spritely.net/

Otherwise, I don't think the problem is within the JS or the CSS, but rather in the way you design your "frames" in the image sprite.  The bouncing effect should be there, in my opinion, not in the script.

Comment: Spritely had crossed my mind.. The problem is that this picture is just stock photography. I don't have a human model that I can pose in different positions or anything. like that.